# Node Ottoman doesn't validate data type

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-ottoman

I'm using ottoman for Couchbase in nodejs, I defined an attribute as `number` in model, Then I passed a `string` type value for that attribute for the model and but it doesn't fail to save. I've asked the same question in github https://github.com/couchbaselabs/node-ottoman/issues/219, its been a month - no response! Appreciate any help.

Thanks